# Dispatch action from saga in order to reach reducer while that action is being watched by the same saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

When I run `getUser()` from my component in order to dispatch a `GET_USER` type action the action is being caught by my saga. Then by using `getUserInfo()` I make a request to fetch some data and in order to update the state, I dispatch a GET_USER_SUCCESS with the results as payload. Is this a bad approach?

Can I somehow dispatch `GET_USER` again from within the saga passing the results as payload without having the saga intercept it so it can reach the reducer?

actionTypes.js

```
export const GET_USER = "GET_USER"
export const GET_USER_SUCCESS = "GET_USER_SUCCESS"
export const GET_USER_FAIL = "GET_USER_FAIL"
```

actions.js

```
import {
    GET_USER,
    GET_USER_SUCCESS,
    GET_USER_FAIL
} from "./actionTypes"

export const getUser = () => ({
    type: GET_USER,
})

export const getUserSuccess = data => ({
    type: GET_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
})

export const getUserFail = error => ({
    type: GET_USER_FAIL,
    payload: error,
})
```

saga.js

```
import { call, put, takeEvery } from "redux-saga/effects"
import { GET_USER } from "./actionTypes"
import { getUser, getUserSuccess, getUserFail } from "./actions"

import { getUserInfo } from "../../../helpers/backend_helper"

function* getUserInformation() {
    try {
        const user_response = yield call(getUserInfo)
        if (user_response && user_response.id)
            yield put(getUserSuccess(user_response))
        else
            yield put(getUserFail('could not fetch user'))
    } 
    catch (error) {
        yield put(apiError("Bad response from server"))
    }
}

function* userSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(GET_USER, getUserInformation)
}

export default userSaga
```

backend_helper.js

```
import { post, del, get, put } from "./api_helper"
const getUserInfo = () => get("/users/me/")
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean by "Can i somehow dispatch GET_USER again from within the saga passing the results as payload without having the saga to intercept it so it can reach the reducer". Your code here looks reasonable.

Comment: Thats good to hear...I mean instead of getUserSuccess(user_response) to use getUser(user_response) without resulting in an infinite loop

Comment: Since you're using `takeEvery`, no, there's no way to dispatch a `GET_USER` action from within your saga without triggering an infinite loop. IMO you're following Redux best practice by having a separate side-effect triggering action (`GET_USER`) and response action (`GET_USER_SUCCESS`). If you want to intercept an action, transform it, and then pass it along without triggering an infinite loop, you can use a standard [Redux middleware](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-4-store#middleware) and call `next({ ...action, data })`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're suggesting also makes things harder to debug. You would want unique actions; GET_USER to tell you that you're fetching data and GET_USER_SUCCESS to tell you that you've successfully received the information.

In complex web applications you could see up to 20, 30, even 40 actions so being able to distinguish them is vital in my opinion.